# Drag Coefficient with respect to velocity

Tags: fluid-dynamics, projectile, drag

As I understand it, drag force of an object in a fluid is given by $F_D = \frac{1}{2}\rho v^2C_DA$, where $\rho$ is density of the fluid, and $v$ is the relative velocity of the flow with respect to the object. We can then solve for drag coefficient $C_D = \frac{2F_D}{\rho v^2A}$.

First question: Does a stationary object in a flow of velocity $v$ result in equal drag force to the same object moving at a velocity $v$ in a stationary fluid?

Second question: It makes sense to me that drag force is related to velocity, and a higher velocity means a higher drag force. However, the drag coefficient, I'm not so sure about. Given an object, does its $C_D$ vary with relative flow velocity? Or is that already factored in because $F_D$ changes as well, and the $C_D$ is only dependent on the geometry of the object?

So basically, if I dragged a submerged square plate through the water, once as fast as possible and once as slow as possible, would the calculated drag coefficients be theoretically the same?

Comment: Suggestion to the post (v2): Replace the word _velocity_ with the word _speed._

Comment: You need to include viscosity effects to get the correct result. Your formula will have ranges of applicability for speed. Also for shape and size of the test object. Just as an example, when  you get near the speed of sound in air, drag does weird things.

Comment: One of my pet peeves (speaking as an Aero engineer) is that so many students are simply taught that first equation as if it told them anything about the drag, when in fact Cd can vary by several orders of magnitude (as shown by @basics excellent answer). I prefer to think of it as simply the definition of Cd.

Comment: @Qmechanic More often than not, Aero engineers will use the word "velocity" when they mean "speed"

Answer (score 3):

1. yes, only relative velocity matters;
2. drag coefficient $C_D$ and other adimensional coefficients, like the lift coefficient of an airfoil or a wing, can be functions of adimensional parameters of the flow, like the Reynolds' number

   $Re = \dfrac{\rho U L}{\mu} = \dfrac{\text{inertia}}{\text{viscosity}}$

   or the Mach's number

   $M = \dfrac{U}{c} = \dfrac{\text{inertia}}{\text{compressibility}}$

   of the flow.

   Thus, aerodynamic coefficients can be function of the velocity, through these adimensional numbers

   $C_x(\alpha, \beta, Re, M, \dots)$,

   being $\alpha$, $\beta$ the angles that describe the relative velocity of the flow w.r.t. the orientation of the object.

   In order to have an example of how the drag coefficient can vary as a function of the velocity, through the Reynolds' number, we can take a look at the plot of the $C_D(Re)$ of a sphere.

[image]